# Spring Cloud Vault - Best place to store the Secret-Id and Role-Id

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am using Spring Cloud Vault Library to access my Secrets from the Vault server.

Currently I am storing all the parameters, such as `role-id`, `secret-id`, `host`, `port`, etc..., as **Environment Variables** and then injecting that in to my `bootstrap.yml` of my Spring-boot App. Below is my `YAML` file

```
spring:
 cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: ${role-id}
        secret-id: ${secret-id}
      host: ${host}
      port: ${port}
      scheme: ${scheme}
```

**Where I am stuck is with Managing the Vault's Role-Id & Secret-Id**. Obviously, Vault is no good at protecting our secrets ***if people can easily get their hands on these 2 pieces of information*** – they are indeed secrets themselves.

What is the Industry best practice to have `Role-Id` and `Secret-Id` protected ? We already brainstormed ideas like *storing-in-config-server*, *storing-in-environment-variable*, *storing-in-cloudfoundry-UPS* ..

Nevertheless we would like to understand the best practice on this ..

Comment: So what did you decide to go with ultimately?

Comment: i used PCF Credhub to store my secret-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced to the same problem and here's what you can do. First of all, application should have defined own system user and it should be launched as that user. Then in the same directory as your jar/war file you can make **bootstrap.properties** file containing:

```
spring.cloud.vault.app-role.secret-id=*your-secret-for-role-id*
```

Here's ls output example:

```
-rw-------. 1 app app bootstrap.properties
-rwxr--r--. 1 app app app.jar
```

Application user has to be an owner of this properties file and only he should be permited to read **bootstrap.properties**. This protects your secret from unauthorized access unless you have root or application user permissions.